# TextView improperly displaying in Layout in Android 6 and below

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am dynamically creating views in onCreate() and then use setMargins() and setLayoutParams() to position them on the layout.

This works as expected in Android 7 but the parameters are ignored in Android 6 and below.

I assume it has something to do with views not being created in onCreate() or something like that but dont know why it would work in Android 7, or how to get around it.

Below is example code of the problem and some screenshots for visualization.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    viewParam.setMargins(200, 400, 0, 0);

    TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);

    myTextView.setText("Hello this is my text");

    myTextView.setTextSize(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 50);

    myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    myTextView.setLayoutParams(viewParam);
    viewGroup.addView(myTextView);

}
```

[image: View on Android 6]
[image: View on Android 7]

Comment: Don't add your `View` to `android.R.id.content`. Add it to a `ViewGroup` in your `activity_main` layout, so you know you've got the right `LayoutParams` type.

Comment: Why dont you just use xml instead of making views programmatically!. It is fast in performance and easy to customize!

Comment: Xenolion - This is just a simple static example of the issue. In my full application I have to dynamically create the view and change it at run time.